# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when deploying two war files in Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, cross-domain, tomcat8

Individually, each WAR file works fine.  However, when I deploy both WAR files in the webApps folder, I get the "crossdomain pre-flight No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error.

The key here is that the FIRST war file I access through a web request works fine.  The second one always fails with this error.  So, with a fresh server restart, WAR file A is accessed first, and it works while WAR file B fails.  Conversely, if I restart the server and WAR file B is accessed first, it works while WAR file A fails.

The COORS headers which allow cross domain web access are located in the web.xml files of each war application.

Thanks in advance for your help!  I am really struggling here.

Ryan

Comment: Is the header being set - i.e., using Firebug or the Chrome tools do you see it set on the HTTP header?  I don't see where you set the headers per se in web.xml - I see that there is a Tomcat specific filter to add them - is that what you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the following to the web.xml of both WAR files:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```